# Embedded video on my angular app exits fullscreen mode automatically in ngx-owl-carousel-o

Tags: html, angular, video, fullscreen, owl-carousel

I am using a carousel package(ngx-owl-carousel-o) to make a video carouselhave the following code in my component.html file:

```
<div class="containers" style="width: 90%; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center;" allowfullscreen="true">
        <owl-carousel-o [options]="customOptions" allowfullscreen="true">
            <ng-template carouselSlide allowfullscreen="true">
                <div class="policy-card" style="padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 10px; background: white;" allowfullscreen="true">
                <div class="policy-img" style="width: 90%; height: 90%; margin:auto; overflow: hidden;" allowfullscreen="true">
                    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" allowfullscreen="true">
                        <video width="500px" height="500px" class="embed-responsive-item" controls="true"> <source src="assets/demo_rel5.mp4" type="video/mp4" ></video>
                     </div>
                </div>
                <h2 style="margin-top:10px; margin-bottom: 0px;"> lorem</h2>
                </div>
            </ng-template>  
            <ng-template carouselSlide><div class="policy-card" style="padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 10px; background: white;">
                <div class="policy-img" style="width: 90%; height: 90%; margin:auto; overflow: hidden;">
                    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                        <video class="embed-responsive-item" controls="true" src="assets/demo_rel5.mp4" allowfullscreen ></video>
                     </div>
                </div>
                <h2 style="margin-top:10px; margin-bottom: 0px;"> lorem</h2>
            </div></ng-template>  
            <ng-template carouselSlide><div class="policy-card" style="padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 10px; background: white;">
                <div class="policy-img" style="width: 90%; height: 90%; margin:auto; overflow: hidden;">
                    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                        <video class="embed-responsive-item" controls="true" src="assets/demo_rel5.mp4" allowfullscreen ></video>
                     </div>
                </div>
                <h2 style="margin-top:10px; margin-bottom: 0px;"> lorem</h2>
            </div></ng-template>  
            <ng-template carouselSlide><div class="policy-card" style="padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 10px; background: white;">
                <div class="policy-img" style="width: 90%; height: 90%; margin:auto; overflow: hidden;">
                    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                        <video class="embed-responsive-item" controls="true" src="assets/demo_rel5.mp4" allowfullscreen ></video>
                     </div>
                </div>
                <h2 style="margin-top:10px; margin-bottom: 0px;"> lorem</h2>
            </div></ng-template>  
          </owl-carousel-o>
    </div>
```

My application is old and made in Angular 7 and so, I am using this carousel's version 1.2.1.

I have the following code in component.ts file:

```
customOptions: any = {
        loop: true,
        mouseDrag: true,
        touchDrag: true,
        pullDrag: true,
        dots: false,
        video:true,
        navSpeed: 700,
        navText: ['<i class="fa fa-caret-left"></i>', '<i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i>'],
        responsive: {
          0: {
            items: 1
          },
          400: {
            items: 2
          },
          740: {
            items: 3
          },
          940: {
            items: 3
          }
        },
        nav: true
      }
```

The carousel is working fine except when I click on full-screen on any of the videos, it goes full screen for around half a second and exits the fullscreen mode instantly.

I only had allowfullscreen in video tag before but i added allowfullscreen to all the parent tags in order to resolve this issue. However, nothing is helping. I also tried replacing `allowfullscreen`
with
`allowfullscreen="true"`
which you can also see in my current code but it is not working